# Heroku NODE_ENV environment variable

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm running a Node project with Heroku as my main deploy target. In dev environment I'm using grunt to start the web server, however in production I prefer to launch the app directly with `node app`

Here's my Procfile:

```
web: bin/web
```

And bin/web:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                       
echo "NODE_ENV=" $NODE_ENV
if [ "$NODE_ENV" == "production" ]; then
    echo "Starting the server with node app"
    node app
else
    echo "Starting the server using grunt"
    grunt
fi
```

The first `echo` is for debugging. heroku log is showing:

```
app[web.1]: NODE_ENV=
```

Basically, meaning NODE_ENV is not set. (and the app starts with grunt instead of `node app`)

The [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support) say that "The NODE_ENV environment variable defaults to production, but you can override it if you wish"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 43):

Not sure if you figured this out or not, but I had the same problem and fixed it using:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Via https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support.

Good luck!

Comment: Did you put this in your procfile?

Comment: I'm an idiot this something you run in command line it just looks similar to procfile so i was confused.